# Repeat (Loop) UIButton besides Play button

Tags: iphone, ios6, uibutton, avaudioplayer

Basically in app have a play button for audio file, want to add another UIButton Besides Play button so that whenever it is pressed it will repeat audio file for some number of times or may be infinite until it is pressed again to stop repetition of playing audio file. How can this be achieved.

Below is the code for play/pause toggle button

```
_playButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[_playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
_playButton.frame = CGRectMake(80, 40, 25, 25);
[_playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1play.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"audiopause.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
UIBarButtonItem *play = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:_playButton];

// Get the file path to the song to play.
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Theme"ofType:@"mp3"];

// Convert the file path to a URL.
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];

//Initialize the AVAudioPlayer.
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
          initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];
player.delegate = self;

- (void)playAction:(id)sender
{
    if([player isPlaying])
    {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1play.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [player pause];
        //[timer invalidate];
        //timer = nil;
        //[self pauseTimer];
    }else{
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"audiopause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [player play];
        slidertimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateProgressBar:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:slidertimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
        timer = slidertimer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all you need is to execute an action every x number of seconds. You can move the code the UIButton is executing to a method, and then have a NSTimer looping that executes that method for n number of times, then invalidate the NSTimer when you are done.

Comment: i want to code for repeat button for audio file so that when user is playing audio file and then presses repeat button for repeating audio file for infinite times or for some number of times. How to code for that repeat button.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally worked it out like this

```
 -(void) RepeatAction:(id)sender{

if (player && player.playing) {

    [player stop];

    player = nil;

    [_playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1play.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    return;
}

// Get the file path to the song to play.

NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Theme"ofType:@"mp3"];

// Convert the file path to a URL.

NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];

//Initialize the AVAudioPlayer.

player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
          initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];

player.delegate = self;

    player.numberOfLoops = -1;

   [player play];

}
```

Now only problem i m facing is that play/pause toggle button is disturbed with this. How to fix that.